# Cómo ocultar pestañas de tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un tabcontrol con 3 pestañas y 3 botones donde cada botón me lleva a una pestaña de ese tabcontrol, lo que quiero es que únicamente los botones cambien de pestaña y no al presionar las pestañas del tabcontrol en si. Entonces se pueden ocultar las pestañas? De manera que no se vean? O se pueden bloquear para que no se de el click en ellas?

Comment: Para que usas un tabcontrol entonces? porque no usar frames unos sobre otros?

Comment: Una manera en la que puedes ocultaros es colocar un control encima de las pestanyas, o, en el caso de que el tabcontrol sea el control mas arriba de la parte superior, poner fuera del formulario las pestañas (Location del TabControl)

Comment: Disculpa la vdd es que soy nuevo en c# y pensé que sería una mejor opción usar el tabcontrol gbianchi.

Comment: Y Marc la vdd es que no había pensado en algo tan sencillo como eso jaja tienes razón dejé las pestañas fuera del formulario y quedó excelente gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 1):

Este solucion es basada en la respuesta de Amr Ashraf en la pregunta StackOverflow [How can I disable a tab inside a TabControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418006/how-can-i-disable-a-tab-inside-a-tabcontrol); y fue probado usando Windows Forms.

*nota: tabControl = pestañas*

Si tienes algo como asi:

[image: TabControl con pestañas]

Cuando presionas button1 y quieres solo tabPage1 para ser visible, puedes "esconder" los otros tabPage con este codigo:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Prueba si tabPage1 esta escondido o no
    if (tabPage1.Parent == null)
    {
        // 0 es el index por la primera pestana
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tabPage1);
    }

    // Desconectar otras tabPage de TabControl para 'esconderlos'
    tabPage2.Parent = null;
    tabPage3.Parent = null;
}
```

Haz lo mismo con los metodos Button2_click y Button3_click

Comment: Luke gracias por el aporte también me funcionó en vdd les agradezco a todos